# How to start an embedded YouTube video at a certain timestamp in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, youtube, video-streaming

I want to start an embedded youtube video from a timestamp. I know how to do it on browsers but that does not seem to work on iPhone. Here is a detailed tutorial by MATT CUTTS.

[Start an embedded video at a certain timestamp](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/start-youtube-video-minutes-seconds/)

In above link you can see if we append #t=31m08s or &start=200 in url it works but when i use same url inside UiWebView, default youtube player starts video from first frame. Can anyone have an idea or have implemented same. I am using UIWebView with embed tag to play youtube video. I am using below embed tag inside UIWebView.

```
 <embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsFQ9kM1qDs" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width= "500" height="400"></embed>
```

Below is the code i am using to play this video in UIWebView

```
- (IBAction) playYoutube {
    [self embedYouTube:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsFQ9kM1qDs#t=2m08s"];
}

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url
{  
    [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>" 
    "<style type=\"text/css\">"
    "body {"
    "background-color: transparent;"
    "color: white;"
    "} </style>"
    "</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"
    "  <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" "
    "width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>"
    "   </body></html>";  

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, webView.frame.size.width,  webView.frame.size.height]; 
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Avinash could you post what`s your code(object-c) so I can make some tests here as well?!

Comment: @Arthur I added a sample code above which i am using.

Comment: @fcukz i didnt find any solution yet. Let me know if you got anything working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Youtube API team there no way to do this with iPhone/iPad etc. - see https://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/ef4f434347622448/0f65f465d671d74c

Comment: Thanks Yahia.. This link makes it sure that there is no workaround with youtube player.

Comment: sorry that there is no way :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `?t=1m10s` at the end of the link

E.g. `src="https://youtu.be/dsFQ9kM1qDs?t=1m10s"`

Note: Make sure that you use `youtu.be` link (the link that you get when you click share button on YouTube) and not `youtube.com` link